# QTreeWidget: Loading large numbers of items?

Tags: qt, pyqt

I'm using a QTreeWidget to display a large number of items (about 50_000) using `addTopLevelItem/addTopLevelItems`, `insertTopLevelItem/insertTopLevelItem` and by setting a parent and preceding item to the `QTreeWidgetItem` initializer (usually I need a combination of these adding methods).
This works fine but freezes the GUI for a bit. Is there a way to either do this faster or in the background, so that the GUI doesn't freeze? Speed is not paramount, not freezing the GUI is the top priority.

Contrived example of the way I currently add items (Python/PyQt5):

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        
        # Tree widget initialization
        tree_widget = QTreeWidget()
        self.layout().addWidget(tree_widget)
        # Main Node 0 initialization
        main_node_0 = QTreeWidgetItem()
        main_node_0.setText(0, "Main Node 0")
        tree_widget.addTopLevelItem(main_node_0)
        # Add children to Main Node 0
        for i in range(50_000):
            child_node = QTreeWidgetItem(main_node_0)
            child_node.setText(0, f"Child Node {i}")
        # Main Node 1 initialization
        main_node_1 = QTreeWidgetItem()
        main_node_1.setText(0, "Main Node 1")
        tree_widget.addTopLevelItem(main_node_1)
        # Add children to Main Node 0
        for i in range(50_000):
            child_node = QTreeWidgetItem(main_node_1)
            child_node.setText(0, f"Child Node {i}")
        
        # ... More code similar to the above
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: The question is too broad, it completely depends on how items are created and how "fast" you want those items be added. A basic solution would be to add items in "batches", start with a certain amount to ensure that the view is displayed, then use QTimer to continuously call a function that will complete the loading at regular intervals, only adding portions of the required items. But, as said, it all depends on how the model data is structured, and what is your major requirement. Otherwise, just add a basic dialog that will display a "loading" status and can only be closed programmatically.

Comment: Consider using `QTreeView` instead of `QTreeWidget`. This however require more programming because you will need to write your own tree model.

Comment: Seeing your code would help us finding some possible bottleneck. What I would suggest is that you create the structure of `QTreeWidgetItem`s BEFORE putting them to the model. I.e. try to minimize the number of calls like `QTreeWidget::addTopLevelItems()` because each of them triggers signals between the model and the view and tries to repaint the view.

Comment: `What I would suggest is that you create the structure of QTreeWidgetItems BEFORE putting them to the model.`
That is a great suggestion, but how can they be created with a parent, without adding them to the model?
I'm using the `QTreeWidgetItem` constructor with the `parent` option and that automatically adds them to the model/GUI.
The others I could group together and add multiple at the same time with `addTopLevelItems/insertTopLevelItems`

Comment: @HiFilethebestfilemanager that only happens if the view has been already visible, and if sorting is already active, otherwise the difference is negligible *unless* the top level item count is very high (in the order of thousands).

Comment: @MaticKukovec create the top level items without parents, then add all the children, *finally* call `addTopLevelItems()`

Comment: @musicamante The OP mentions he adds about 50000 items, which is definitely in order of thousands. And adding items one by one to the model, even though you can create the whole structure of the items and add them in one function call, is definitely a premature pesimization.

Comment: @MaticKukovec You can create a `QList` of top level items and add children to each of the top level items using `QTreeWidgetItem::addChild()` or `QTreeWidgetItem::addChildren()`. And once you have the whole structure ready, you just call `QTreeWidget::addTopLevelItems()`. I.e. you insert all the items to the model in just one call.

Comment: @HiFilethebestfilemanager I specifically talked about the *top level item count*. They didn't clarify if that count is just about top level items or *including* child items, that's why I pointed out the difference: for what we know, it could be like a file system, that has thousands (or millions) of items, but only few top level items. Also, child items can be created using the parent item as argument in the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of code restructuring and testing I can confirm that both `@musicamante`'s suggestion:

> create the top level items without parents, then add all the children, finally call addTopLevelItems()

and `@HiFile.app - best file manager`'s suggestion:

> You can create a QList of top level items and add children to each of the top level items using QTreeWidgetItem::addChild() or QTreeWidgetItem::addChildren(). And once you have the whole structure ready, you just call QTreeWidget::addTopLevelItems(). I.e. you insert all the items to the model in just one call.

are the best solution! It might take some effort to restructure the code, but the result is great: no delays in rendering large numbers of items with.

Thank you both for the answer!